# Java input nextLine after another nextLine

Tags: java, input

Code:

```
public void addTest(int idUser) throws IOException {

    String date = null;
    String tec = null;

    System.out.println("Enter name for test file :");
    String file = input.next(); //Name of file

    System.out.println("Enter date formatted as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm :");
    date = input.nextLine(); //String 2 parts
    input.next();

    System.out.println("Enter technician name :");
    tec = input.nextLine(); // String 2+ parts
    input.next();

    String path = "C:\\Test\\Sample\\" + file;
    String chain = readFile(path);

    ClinicalTest test = new ClinicalTest(chain, date, idUser, tec);
    System.out.println(test.getDate()+"\n" + test.getTec());

    createTest(test);
}
```

When enter date **12-12-2018 13:45** and tec name **Mark Zus**, trying to create **test** fails.
sysout only shows **13:45**.

[image]

I tried `input.next()` under each `nextLine()` because if I don't, never let me complete date field.

[image]

This is what happen if only use `nextLine()` for each entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to read [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) which is helpful in using methods. As it is written above the `nextLine()` method:

> This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line
>   separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next
>   line.

It means that by using `next()` method you are reading the first part of your input and then when you use `nextLine()` it captures the rest of the line which is **13:45** in your input sample.

So you don't need `input.next()`. The following code works perfectly:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String date = null;
    String tec = null;

    System.out.println("Enter name for test file :");
    String file = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter date formatted as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm :");
    date = input.nextLine(); //String 2 parts

    System.out.println("Enter technician name :");
    tec = input.nextLine(); // String 2+ parts
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was my first guess. I add the screen for what happen when I do that.

Comment: EDIT: Just create a local Scanner for that method and works great. May be some issue with global scanner. Thanks!